# Can I write shell script in robot framework

Tags: shell, scripting, robotframework

Sh test.sh var1 var2 var3 is one of the test case in my shell scripting is it possible to write in robot framework

I am writing this command in Linux operating system CentOS .

As i found some suggestions I don't want to connect to linux operating system.

Directly i want to execute the command is it possible .

If soo please provide me an example.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you are writing the command in linux but don't want to "connect to linux". What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process Library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html)

`Run Process   ./test.sh var1 var2 var3` for example

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).